# why pcre generate so many soft links?

Tags: linux, pcre

i build pcre from source and install it to my home directory, now i am in $HOME/build/lib directory, and found many soft links, just confused about this, why pcre generate so many soft links?

```
ls -l
total 792
-rw-r--r-- 1 hugemeow hugemeow 380308 Oct  2 19:21 libpcre.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 hugemeow hugemeow  35998 Oct  2 19:21 libpcrecpp.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 hugemeow hugemeow   1008 Oct  2 19:21 libpcrecpp.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 hugemeow hugemeow     19 Oct  2 19:21 libpcrecpp.so -> libpcrecpp.so.0.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 hugemeow hugemeow     19 Oct  2 19:21 libpcrecpp.so.0 -> libpcrecpp.so.0.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 hugemeow hugemeow  41246 Oct  2 19:21 libpcrecpp.so.0.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 hugemeow hugemeow    939 Oct  2 19:21 libpcre.la
-rw-r--r-- 1 hugemeow hugemeow  10860 Oct  2 19:21 libpcreposix.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 hugemeow hugemeow   1022 Oct  2 19:21 libpcreposix.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 hugemeow hugemeow     21 Oct  2 19:21 libpcreposix.so -> libpcreposix.so.0.0.2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 hugemeow hugemeow     21 Oct  2 19:21 libpcreposix.so.0 -> libpcreposix.so.0.0.2
-rwxr-xr-x 1 hugemeow hugemeow  13140 Oct  2 19:21 libpcreposix.so.0.0.2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 hugemeow hugemeow     16 Oct  2 19:21 libpcre.so -> libpcre.so.1.2.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 hugemeow hugemeow     16 Oct  2 19:21 libpcre.so.1 -> libpcre.so.1.2.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 hugemeow hugemeow 294214 Oct  2 19:21 libpcre.so.1.2.1
drwxrwxr-x 2 hugemeow hugemeow   4096 Oct  2 19:21 pkgconfig
```